# How to pass MVC action and controller name in jQuery History PushState and read the culture from URL?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, pushstate

I am working with multi-lingual MVC application. I am using history push state at many places in my application. And it was working absolutely fine until I changed it to multi-lingual. My current code:

```
history.pushState(null, null, '/Employees/Edit/@ViewBag.Id');
```

Now, my URL changed to:

> /en-US/Employees/Edit/@ViewBag.Id

And

> /ar-SA/Employees/Edit/@ViewBag.Id

I am trying to save culture in `ViewBag` and use `if-statement` here to check the culture. But it is not working. How can I read the culture through URL without using `If-Statement`.

Comment: but just build this into the Routes....., that would be the smartest then you dont need anything else... i believe your problem is around viewbag incorrect usage or non siutable usage more than the actual change you want. how is viewBag.id gona work... just use the actual values.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var url = '/Employees/Edit'+ @ViewBag.Id

history.pushState(null, null,url );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add the language section into your route and then use it with the pushState
like

```
history.pushState(null, null, 
    '@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["lang"]/Employees/Edit/@ViewBag.Id');
```